# Firebase Web Automatically insert createdAt and updatedAt fields

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been using Firebase for one of my projects, but I've noticed that it doesn't automatically add the createdAt and updatedAt fields like Mongodb would add. How would I achieve the same functionality within Google Firebase? I've been looking for some sort of event or function I could override to add the fields but I haven't had any luck!

Comment: You mean createdOn and modifiedOn datetime fields for the json object ?

Comment: Yep, every time I set something in the database I'm wanting it to do it for me so each time I add something I don't need to keep updating a modifiedOn and createdOn field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using [Firebase Cloud Functions.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) Please have a look at it.

Below is the sample code, which you can use it to achieve.

```
exports.generateCreatedOn = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}/')
    .onWrite(event => {
      return event.data.ref.child('createdOn').set(new String(new Date()));
    });
```

Here, I've set the path to `/messages/{pushId}/` this leads to repeated function triggers. So please find correct code below,

```
exports.generateCreatedOn = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}/someKnownKey')
        .onWrite(event => {
          return event.data.ref.parent.child('createdOn').set((new Date()).getTime());
        });
```

but you have to apply same logic for whatever path you are using. And, I've set only `createdOn`, Please use similar logic for `modifiedOn`.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the help, one more thing is there something within Firebase that works likes mongoDB's populate function? for instance populating a user fields that's within a post entry?

Comment: I haven't tried mongoDB' populate. If you explain the functionality, I'll try to sort out in firebase way.

Comment: All is good, I've figured out how I can achieve the same functionality

Comment: mongo's populate function it's something like a join in sql, it allows to get the object from a reference. As far as i know, there isn't something like this in firebase, you need to ask for the object through the reference in a new call